# Add where condition on a nested relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add a where condition on a nested relationship of my model, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
INNER JOIN products p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.created_at > '2019-12-01';
```

What I do in laravel is:

```
$this->builder->where('products.date', '>', '2019-12-01');
```

And it's obviously working perfectly. The problem is that if I replace it with:

```
$this->builder->whereHas('products', function ($query) {
  $query->where('date', '>', '2019-12-01');
});
```

it's not working anymore as expected. That's because in the second case, laravel adds a following query:

```
and exists (SELECT * from products where users.id = products.user_id and date > '2019-12-01')
```

so in this case, my `JOIN` is not applied to my where condition, and I'm getting too many results.

Is there a way to apply a nested `where` condition, using eloquent relationships,  that would work like my first example?

Comment: According to this post, the raw query will be `and exists (SELECT * from products where users.id = products.user_id  and date > '2019-12-01') `, I think you forget post some code.

Comment: so did u `join` `products` before `$this->builder->whereHas`? can u post your code about  `$this->builder`

Answer (score 2):

Use `with` for this kinda scenario.

```
$this->builder->with(['products'=>function ($query) {
  $query->where('date', '>', '2019-12-01');
}]);
```

with this, You will get `users` with `products`. But `products` have filtered as `date > 2019-12-01`

You can do it with `carbon` and `whereDate` as well.

```
$date =Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-12-01')->format('Y-m-d');

$this->builder->with(['products'=>function ($query) use($date) {
  $query->whereDate('date', '>', $date);
}]);
```

Comment: It's kind of working, because I can access the results, but it's not applied as a where condition - it just gives me the filtered data I can get separately.

Comment: This query is the same as your first join query. and if you check your query log then you can find out what was the last executed query, check this link. https://artisansweb.net/how-to-log-query-in-laravel/ and if you want to use where condition on relationship then you need to follow query builder not relationship.